# WPF one ViewModel as a property of MainWindow, how to access ViewModel from pages properly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am pretty new in WPF and .NET C# but still can make one page app. The problem begins when I want to have 2 pages and a navigation between them. I have one ViewModel and 2 pages: KlantenPage.xaml.cs (with a view Klanten.xaml) and BookingPage.xaml.cs (with the view BookingPage.xaml). I have two navigation buttons in the Main Window. I also want to save the data in both pages on closing event.

My MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="KlantenAppWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KlantenAppWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Klanten" Height="35" Width="100" Content="Toon klanten" IsEnabled="False" Click="NavigateToKlanten"/>
        <Button x:Name="Bookingen" Height="35" Width="100" Content="Toon bookingen" IsEnabled="True" Click="NavigateToBookingen"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Source="KlantenPage.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Visible" Visibility="Visible"></Frame>
</DockPanel>
```

My MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
      MainViewModel _viewM = null;
      public MainViewModel ViewM
      {
          get { _viewM ??= new MainViewModel(); return _viewM; }
          set => _viewM = value;
      }
  
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewM.KlantenLijst.Import();//load data from json file
        ViewM.BookingLijst.Import();//load data from json file
        DataContext = ViewM;
  }
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {            
        ViewM?.BookingLijst?.SaveData();//export to json file with all changes, done by the user
        ViewM?.KlantenLijst?.SaveData();//export to json file with all changes, done by the user
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

    private void NavigateToBookingen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   ViewM?.KlantenLijst?.SaveData();
        MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("BookingPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));            
        Bookingen.IsEnabled = false;
        Klanten.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    private void NavigateToKlanten(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        ViewM?.BookingLijst?.SaveData();
        MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("KlantenPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));            
        Bookingen.IsEnabled = true;
        Klanten.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

So, I've created an instance of a class MainViewModel (= ViewM), but my pages don't have access to this.
My KlantenPage.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
public partial class KlantenPage : Page
{ 

  // MainViewModel ViewM = ??????????.ViewM;
  //I really don't know how to call the ViewM property of MainWindow here. 
          
    public KlantenPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //DataContext = ViewM;
    }
```

How can I connect my pages to the mainWindow? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM Architecture is based on transferring data from the **Model** to the **View** only through the view model.
Therefore you should, by the architecture **DRY** rules to use a **View model** to every **view**.
That way you can keep the 1:1 relationship between the views and view-models.

It doesn't always have to be this way, but because it is your beginning in the MVVM world, i suggest you create a view model to every page in your program and connect them to the same **Model** (witch is your back-end algorithm and logic), and that is how you should transfer the data from page to page.

Comment: Thak you, but even if I have done this (I tried this too), I still don't know how the mainWindow and pages interact. And the big Model I should make in mainWindow, not?

Comment: You should use the DataContext property to bind the ViewModel to the View